how to change v-calendar default color using vue.js 3

<template>
  <v-row>
    <v-col>
      <v-sheet>
        <v-calendar class="custom"></v-calendar>
      </v-sheet>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</template>
<style>
  .custom {
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    color: brown;
  }
  .custom button {
    color: crimson;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
 
</style>


It seems that customizing button colors does not cover all buttons in a component. The color of the Today button does not change. How can I overwrite the color of this button?
And how can I add  @click function that it only works only when the button is clicked, not other elements in the component.
I try this but it not work to all button
 .custom button {
    color: crimson;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    box-shadow: none;
  }

and the second question
I do the function @click  but I want it to work only when click on button not entire component
like when I click on day name it run function too.
<v-calendar @click="doSomething"> </v-calendar>


Mind providing a [repro] to help you with that one?

The default color for today is primary, you can override it like below:
<v-calendar color="red"></v-calendar>

If you want to directly use your customized color like <v-calendar color="aquamarine"></v-calendar>, I think you should add the color into the theme configuration like below:
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
export default createVuetify({
  theme: {
    defaultTheme: 'myCustomTheme',
    themes: {
      myCustomTheme: {
        dark: false,
        colors: {
          ..., // We have omitted the standard color properties here to emphasize the custom one that we've added
          aquamarine: '#00ff00',
        },
      },
    },
  },

})
Regarding the 2nd question, I don't think there is a click event of the day cell, instead, you can try the slot for the event if clicking on the event is also ok for you.
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-calendar/#slots
